# where do I put my `pg_hba.conf` file in EnterpriseDB for OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, enterprisedb

I have a `pg_hba.conf.sample` file, but no `pg_hba.conf` file. I want to make one and put it in the right place. Where do I put `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to EnterpriseDB documentation (Chapter 18.2 File locations):

> By default, all three configuration files are stored in the database
>   cluster's data directory.

http://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/8.4/pg/runtime-config-file-locations.html#GUC-HBA-FILE

have a look in your postgres.conf for the 'data_directory' setting

another way to get the location of your data_directory is to execute a SQL query with admin privileges

For example:

```
postgres=# SHOW data_directory;
 data_directory  
-----------------
 /var/pgsql/data
```

and it might look as follows:

```
[root@host /var/pgsql/data]# ls
base    pg_clog      pg_ident.conf  pg_notify  pg_stat_tmp  pg_tblspc    PG_VERSION  postgresql.conf  postmaster.pid
global  pg_hba.conf  pg_multixact   pg_serial  pg_subtrans  pg_twophase  pg_xlog     postmaster.opts
```

If the pg_hba.conf is not present here, put it into the directory which has been provided by the SHOW data_directory SQL query